# Почему не сравниваются числа?

Tags: c, символы

Всегда заходит в if. При том, что длинна ровна 3 и выводит это,if всегда выдает 1, в чем проблема ?

```
flag=0;
    printf("Enter adress\n" );
    scanf("%s",adress);
    while (getchar() != '\n')
      continue;

    if (strlen(adress)!='3') {
      printf("lent is %li\n",strlen(adress) );
      flag = 1;
      printf("Invalid lenth\n");
    }
```

Comment: Почему вы взяли 3 в кавычки?

Comment: Я просто python использую а тут заставили курсовую сдавать на C, вот и пытаюсь быстро заполнить пробел, думал раз с такой типизированый весь там так нужно, ведь числа то так объявлял  : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь

```
strlen(adress)!='3'
```

вы сравниваете длину строки `adress` со значением **символа** `'3'`, т.е. в обычных ASCII - 51...

Если хотите сравнивать с тройкой - так и пишите:

```
strlen(adress)!=3
```